# rails for loop produces extra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting extra empty loop with this simple partial for images:
basically i got 3 images in the album and i keep getting 4 loops(1 empty extra). Any simple solutions ?

```
<% @album.pictures.each do |picture|%>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-thumbnail">
         <%= image_tag picture.file_url((:album),:class=> "img-responsive") if picture.file? %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="lead">name</p>
        <p>description</p>
        <p>
            <%= button_to "remove", album_picture_path(:picture_id => picture.id, :album_id => @album.id), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => :destroy %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!--/col-->
   <% end %>
```

**Picture Controller.rb**

```
def index
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @albumpicture = @album.pictures
    @pictures = @albumable.pictures.all
    render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
  end

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pictures }
    end
  end

  def new
    @album = Album.find(params[:gallery_id])
    #@picture = @album.pictures.build
    #@picture = Picture.new(:album_id => params[:album_id])
  end
```

**Album_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @albums = @albumable.albums
       respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @albums }
    end
  end

  def show

    @album = @albumable.albums.find(params[:id])
    # @picture = @album.pictures.build
    # @pictures = Picture.find(:all, :conditions => ['album_id = ?', @album.id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @album }
    end

  end

  def new
    @album = @albumable.albums.new
    @album.token = @album.generate_token
    # @picture = @album.pictures.build
    # @pictures = []

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @album }
    end
  end
```

**_fileupload.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @album.pictures.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
```

Comment: You probably have a new picture object initialized in controller: `@album.pictures.new` that will add this object to already existing ones in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain my above comment in details, let's say you have a controller action where you initialize a new picture object that you want to use in form:

```
def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  @new_picture = @album.pictures.new
end
```

at this moment let's say this album has no picture in it, in show.html.erb if you'd do `<%= @album.pictures.count %>` you'd expect to have `0` as result, but it will be `1` as you have one picture object initialized in album even if the picture was not saved.

What I do in this cases, I remove the new object from controller and put it directly in the form:

```
<%= form_for @album.pictures.new, do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for Picture.new, do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :album_id %>
<% end %>
```

and you make sure `album_id` is saved when you save the picture, if not in rails 3 you might need to set it in `attr_accessible` in `Picture.rb`

Comment: Added the controllers, still getting the same extra without the creating new objects.

Comment: Where exactly you display the pictures? In what action/page?

Comment: Also, tell me please, the form is above the pictures? In html I mean, it's form first then gallery, or it's gallery then form? If form is first, and you initialize an object before doing `@album.pictures` will add a new object to the gallery too. So I would try to do `@pictures = @album.pictures` in controller, then use `@pictures` and `@album.pictures.new` in html.